# Confusion regarding selection of identical objects and their distribution in identical boxes

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I have a confusion regarding the following question.....
What are no. of ways in which 5 identical balls can be distributed in 10 identical boxes such that no box gets more than 1 ball??

Now....according to me since the objects as well as places are identical and no distinction can be made for the same....the no. of ways of doing the above task should be equal to 1.

But the answer key mentions another answer at the back of my book.....so is my method incorrect or is it a case of typo(the question was in mcq section)?

Comment: If the problem means what it says, your answer is correct, else there is a typo in the question.

Comment: Your answer is correct for the problem as stated. What was the other answer? $252$?

Comment: Yeh exactly it was given as (10 C 5) ie 252...

Comment: I guess its a typo in the question itself...